# VS2013: Restore classic find window and wildcard search

Tags: visual-studio-2013

They replaced the Find window (Ctrl+F) in Visual Studio 2013, in comparison with Visual Studio 2010. It is now a minimalistic search bar like window in the top right corner of the editor area and it does instant search in the actual file. This drives me crazy. Not to mention the absence of the "wildcard" option and the ambiguous visualization of switches (very thin border around [Aa], [.*], etc...). All in all, I don't like it.

Unfortunately the "Find in files" (Ctrl+Shift+F) now also don't have wildcards. At least it remained non-instant and big.

- Can I restore the wildcard search somehow?
- Can I have Ctrl+F to raise a window for searching in the current file?

Do you know any helpful settings or extensions for these goals?

Comment: Just [reassign the Ctrl+F key](http://grantwinney.com/making-the-find-and-replace-search-box-the-default-in-visual-studio-2013/).  You'll have to get used to regular expressions.

Comment: @HansPassant Reassign the Ctrl+F key to do what? To have one more shortcut to a place that I already can access otherwise? Also, I am quite used to regular expressions. I wrote a modular Chomsky type 3 class language myself.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question *The Visual Studio 2013’s Find and Replace Dialog provides the option for the user to find and replace text in the project using regular expressions or wildcards*.,I guess this is what you are looking for.

- Open the Find and Replace Dialog in Visual Studio.
  [image]
- In the Find and Replace Dialog, click the “+” button before the label “Find Options” to expand the options.
  [image]
- The (a) + button opens up the expression builder that lets you choose
  the regular expression to search for. This can be a useful feature
  especially when you dont know regular expression very well but want
  to try out one of the predefined regular expression.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer any of my questions.

Comment: He is asking for `wildcard` not regular expresison. his next question is opening classic search, which was opening using `CTRL-F` in visual studio 2010. what you explain the same window that was opening with CTRL-SHIFT-F in 2010 version.